# Pagedown markdown script inserts image url once

Tags: javascript, jquery, hook, markdown, pagedown

I have a modified pagedown markdown markup script for inserting image url to the editor but it works only the first time.

I have explained my code with comments

```
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
 var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
 var help = function () { window.open('http://mywebsite.com/editing-help'); }
 var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
 editor.hooks.set('insertImageDialog', function(callback) {
 setTimeout(function () 
{
        //i use bootstrap dialog to enter the url
        $('#fileModal').modal('show');  

        /*i have a button for clearing the textbox when i open 
        it the second time since when i open it the second 
        time the modal still contains what i had placed previously*/
        $("#clear").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
          $("#imgt").val(''); 
          $("#file").val('');
        });


        //the button that when clicked inserts the image url
        $("#insert_image_post").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        //the image file being inserted
        if($("#imgt").val().length > 0)
        {
            var $url    =   $('input[type=text]');
            var image   =   $("#imgt").val();
            callback(image);
            $("#fileModal").modal('hide');

        }

    });


 }, 0);
return true; // tell the editor that we'll take care of getting the image url
 });

editor.run();

})();
</script>
```

Any one with pagedown markdown javascript... ideas to help me understand where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work

Its like markdown editor does not smoothly run the `.on("click", function(e)...` in my case. i.e.

```
$("#insert_image_post").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

So i used theirs after going through their `Markdown.Editor.js` file i.e.

```
var thebtn = document.getElementById("insert_image_post");
thebtn.onclick = function () {
```

The full adjusted code below

```
<script>
(function () {
 var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
 var help = function () { window.open('http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help'); }
 var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);

 editor.hooks.set("insertImageDialog", function (callback) {

        $('#fileModal').modal('show');

            var thebtn = document.getElementById("insert_image_post");
            thebtn.onclick = function () {
                var images  =   $(".img-url").val();
                callback(images)
                 $('#fileModal').modal('hide');
            };

            var theclear = document.getElementById("clear");
            theclear.onclick = function () {

                  $("#imgt").val(''); 
                  $("#file").val('');

            };

    return true; // tell the editor that we'll take care of getting the image url
});

editor.run();

})();

</script>
```